# ValueError when executing softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow

I am following the [tensorflow tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/). There has been recent tensor flow update in which the cost function `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` has been modified. Hence the code in the tutorial is giving the following error:

`ValueError: Only call softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits with named arguments (labels=..., logits=..., ...)`

What does it mean and how to rectify it?

Here's the entire code till that point:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot = True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

def neural_network_model(data):
hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                  'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                  'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                  'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])),}


l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

return output

def train_neural_network(x):
prediction = neural_network_model(x)
cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y)
```

to

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y)
```

Comment: Validated. I found updating Tensorflow from 0.11 to 1.00 causes many errors. These errors can be solved by backing to Tensorflow old version once and for all. I wish to use v1.0, so have to manually debug each one,  like this thread points out.

Answer (score 4):

the function `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` has been deprecated. The new function is `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2`

```
cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(pred, y))
```

[Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the code donot support Tensorflow v 1.0
It works well when you make slight changes to the following lines of code:
replace

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
```

with 
 `cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))`